# How to transform an entire colum with strings in numbers?

Tags: pandas

what's up?

In excel i could transform an entire column of dates or string in number using number_value formula. Can I do something like this in Python with pandas at on my dataFrames?

Tks

Comment: yes, see `pd.to_numeric` or `df[col].astype(int) or (float)`

Answer (score 0):

The code below should transform string values to a numeric value. The first line is only needed if you are transforming dates from a string to a number.

```
df['col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'])
df['col'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col'])
```